# How can I use a content type field on the body of the e-mail message template on the Webform module?

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

For usability matters, I would like to let the editor create his own confirmation message on my Event content type. So I create a field for that. I also have another field to select which webform is going to be used as a reference (I am doing that the same way that was done on the Event Demo that comes on the module).

Is there a way to use this content type field on the e-mail handler on the webform as a token or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

After looking more the examples, I found this token:

```
[webform_submission:node:field_name_of_the_field]
```

I needed only to replace field_name_of_the_field with the field I want to use.